# Como contar los arreglos que existen dentro de otro arreglo

Tags: php, array

Muy buenas tardes mi estimada comunidad

Es un gusto saludarlos.  Quisiera que por favor me ayuden con la siguiente situación, con información que recojo de los radio buttons y que se asocian a preguntas. creo un array multidimensional.

```
var list = {'datos' :[]};

                $("input:radio:checked").each(function () {
                    list.datos.push({
                        "pregunta": $(this).attr("id"),
                        "solucion": $(this).val(),
                        "modulo": modulo,
                        "batch": idBatch,
                      });
                });

                json = JSON.stringify(list);
                let obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

esto genera un arreglo que paso a PHP mediante AJAX y lo recorro de la siguiente manera

```
    $preguntas = $_POST['obj'];
    
    foreach ($preguntas as $valor) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            echo ' pregunta: ' . $valor[$i]['pregunta'];
            echo ' solucion: ' . $valor[$i]['solucion'];
            echo ' modulo: ' . $valor[$i]['modulo'];
            echo ' batch: ' . $valor[$i]['batch'];
        }
    }
```

Lo que no he podio realizar y me gustaría que me ayudaran es a conocer como contar los arreglos internos, que por ahora lo tengo fijo en 6, pero en la realidad es una variable.

Por consola me arroja el siguiente **resultado**:

```
pregunta: 1 solucion: 1 modulo: 2 batch: 10pregunta: 2 solucion: 1 modulo: 2 batch: 10pregunta: 3 solucion: 1 modulo: 2 batch: 10pregunta: 4 solucion: 1 modulo: 2 batch: 10pregunta: 5 solucion: 1 modulo: 2 batch: 10pregunta: 6 solucion: 1 modulo: 2 batch: 10
```

Resultado de `var_dump($_POST);`:

```
 array(1) { 
    ["datos"]=> array(6) { 
        [0]=> array(4) { 
            ["pregunta"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["solucion"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["modulo"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["batch"]=> string(2) "10" 
                        } 
        [1]=> array(4) { 
            ["pregunta"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["solucion"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["modulo"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["batch"]=> string(2) "10" 
                        } 
        [2]=> array(4) { 
            ["pregunta"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["solucion"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["modulo"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["batch"]=> string(2) "10" 
                        } 
        [3]=> array(4) { 
            ["pregunta"]=> string(1) "4" 
            ["solucion"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["modulo"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["batch"]=> string(2) "10" 
                        } 
        [4]=> array(4) { 
            ["pregunta"]=> string(1) "5" 
            ["solucion"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["modulo"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["batch"]=> string(2) "10" 
                        } 
        [5]=> array(4) { 
            ["pregunta"]=> string(1) "6" 
            ["solucion"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["modulo"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["batch"]=> string(2) "10" 
                        } 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando hablas de *arreglos internos*? Haz un `var_dump($_POST);`, agrega el resultado a la pregunta y explícanos ahí cuáles son esos *arreglos internos* de los que hablas y qué es lo que quieres saber/obtener de ellos. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Otra cosa, si lo que quieres es saber cuántos sub-arrays existen, para establecer el total del `for` interno que tienes en tu código, eso no es necesario, puedes abrir otro `foreach` interno sin contador, simplificando así el código, algo asi más o menos: `foreach ($preguntas as $valor) { foreach ($valor as $item) { //aquí $item sería cada sub-array y puedes leerlo como $item["clave"] } }`. Lo básico es que expliques lo que quieres hacer y quizá podremos sugerirte mejores soluciones con un código más sencillo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya subi el var_dump

Comment: Me he permitido identar la salida del `var_dump`. Para las pruebas, si pones algo como `echo "<pre>";` antes de la salida del `var_dump`, verás la salida identada (organizada) y podrás analizar mejor el dato. Como te decía, tienes un array asociativo y puedes leerlo abriendo otro `foreach` interno. No tienes necesidad de contar primero los elementos para luego usar `$i` para acceder a cada sub-array.

Comment: En el caso que muestras, si la clave se llama `datos` en  `$_POST`, podrías hacer algo así: **`foreach ($_POST["datos"] as $item) { foreach ($item as $k=>$v) { echo "$k: $v\n"; } }`** OBSERVA que ni siquiera necesitas extraer nominalmente cada nombre de clave como `pregunta, solucion, modulo, batch`, etc. OJO: Los datos que muestras en el `var_dump` no coinciden para nada con esto que muestras en tu código: `$preguntas = $_POST['obj'];`, no veo ninguna clave `obj` en la salida que muestras por lo que no sé de donde sacas ese `obj` ¿?

Answer (score 1):

El numero de items en un array se puede obtener de la funcion `count($array)`. Aqui en este caso $valor es el array de preguntas.

```
foreach ($preguntas as $valor) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($valor); $i++) {
        echo ' pregunta: ' . $valor[$i]['pregunta'];
        echo ' solucion: ' . $valor[$i]['solucion'];
        echo ' modulo: ' . $valor[$i]['modulo'];
        echo ' batch: ' . $valor[$i]['batch'];
    }
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php

La otra forma mas practica de recorrerlo es usando `foreach()`.  La variable `$i` es el indice del array. En este caso no seria usado ya que `$pregunta` corresponde al item actual en el loop, no requiere saber la posicion a menos que lo necesites.

```
foreach ($preguntas as $valor) {
    foreach($valor as $i => $pregunta) {
        echo ' pregunta: ' . $pregunta['pregunta'];
        echo ' solucion: ' . $pregunta['solucion'];
        echo ' modulo: ' . $pregunta['modulo'];
        echo ' batch: ' . $pregunta['batch'];
    }
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Si asumimos que `$_POST` (el cual es un array) tiene la estructura que muestras en el `var_dump`, podrías hacer una lectura simple de los datos con este código:

```
foreach ($_POST["datos"] as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k=>$v) {
        echo "$k: $v\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

La salida será la siguiente:

```
pregunta: 1
solucion: 1
modulo: 2
batch: 10

pregunta: 2
solucion: 1
modulo: 2
batch: 10

pregunta: 3
solucion: 1
modulo: 2
batch: 10

pregunta: 4
solucion: 1
modulo: 2
batch: 10

pregunta: 5
solucion: 1
modulo: 2
batch: 10

pregunta: 6
solucion: 1
modulo: 2
batch: 10
```

Como podrás comprobar, no necesitas conocer de antemano cuantos elementos hay en cada array. Y, para este caso, en `$k` y en `$v` tendrás los valores correspondientes a cada clave y valor dentro de los sub-arrays.

Puedes [<kbd>**`VER DEMO`**</kbd>](https://rextester.com/BUJCY15446) en línea y hacer pruebas.